# Get the current url i have loaded in the browser and not the one being $.get by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a controller called `examples.php` and in it i have this function called

```
 public function total_records_of_current_dataset(){
    $url = base_url().uri_string();
    $get_current_segment = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $count_all_rows = $this->db->count_all($get_current_segment);
    echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
    }
```

In my browser i have loaded a page using this url

`http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/offices_management/arminvanbuuren` and i can see the page.In that page a i have div which i am refreshing every 30 seconds.

To refresh the div,i am using this code

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/total_records_of_current_dataset",
  success: function(data){
     $('#total_rows').text(data);
  }
});
}, 3000);
```

Whenever i run the code controller function does not give me the last segment of the url which can be got using `$get_current_segment = $this->uri->segment(3);`

I have tried php $GLOBALS but the current url seem to be the one being requested by the jquery function and not the page i am in right now.

How can i get the last uri segment of `http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/offices_management/arminvanbuuren` which is `arminvanbuuren`?.

Answer (score 0):

To get it,

To get it at a lower level:

```
$uri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$last_part = array_pop($uri);
echo $last_part;
```

Comment: That shows me this url `http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/total_records_of_current_dataset` which is the one i am `$.get` ing but i want this one `http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/offices_management/arminvanbuuren` which i am on.

Comment: This `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` also fetches `http://localhost/fi/index.php/examples/total_records_of_current_dataset`

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it using `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` which gave me the actual browser url.

My final function

```
public function total_records_of_current_dataset(){
$current_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$end = end((explode('/', rtrim($current_url, '/'))));
$count_all_rows = $this->db->count_all($end);
echo $count_all_rows;
}
```